# I need to delete these template areas, having trouble (screenshots)

Tags: magento-1.9, template-hints

With direction, I have turned on 'template path hints'. This means I can see the paths of the template files I should be focusing on.

[image]

I have found these files and deleted them completely from the server (i made backups). My problem is, even after deleting the files they still appear on the landing page with the same template hint paths..

Maybe I need to be editing these files, not deleting them. But I wouldn't know where to start.

EDIT: The line of code seen in the inspect element tool, which when deleted has the desired visual effect. In understand that Magento doesn't work in this way, but I am confused at the ease in which this simple div class can give me my desired results when deleted. Yet making this happen in the 'Magento' way is like drawing blood from stone.

[image]

Comment: If you just deleted files from you theme folder, Magento will fallback to previous theme, you should remove them either via xml or simply erase the content of file, don't delete it(Not recommended).

Comment: I'm still having no luck getting rid of any of these elements. What part of the code is controlling where different elements, like price.phtml, summary_short.phtml, new_grid.phtml (as seen above) are placed / seen. Simply deleting the contents doesn't seem to have much of an effect. I'm trying to wrap my head around the structure of how these elements are displayed.

Comment: I know Magento doesn't work in the way I am about to explain, but when inspecting the elements through my browser, I can simply delete the line of code relating to a class div.std which contains everything I am trying to rid of and successfully remove the whole thing from the landing page.

Comment: A few references that may help: https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento-debugging-loading-blocks-layouts-and-config-files, http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/ and I would recommend Alan Storms No Frills Layout book & http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout